# Trying to uninstall JDK in Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to remove all the JDK's in my computer and only install the LTS version (JDK11).

When i run:
`archlinux-java status`
I get 3 environments ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRjb5.png)).
When i run `pacman -Qe` no JDK is listed, and when i run `pacman -R openjdk14` the terminal returns "No package was found", but when i run `java -version` the OpenJDK-14 is listed ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKvPu.png)). How can i remove all the JDK's in my arch system?

Answer (score 4):

Use `pacman -Q | grep jre` to find the names of the Java packages installed. The switch `-e` limits the output to explicit installed packages. In order to find everything you should'nt use any filters:

```
neon: ~ $ pacman -Qe | grep jre
neon: ~ $ pacman -Q | grep jre
jre-openjdk 14.0.2.u12-1
jre-openjdk-headless 14.0.2.u12-1
```

To remove a package use `pacman -R <package name>` or `pacman -Rs <package name>` if you want to remove unused dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command
`sudo pacman -R jre14-openjdk`

Answer (score 0):

This command will remove the OpenJDK package and its dependencies. `-R` removes the package, `-n` removes all unneeded dependencies, and `-s` removes all configuration files.

```
sudo pacman -Rns jdk-openjdk
```